# xampp not responding to external request

Tags: xampp

i am trying to run xampp on the internal network but it is not responding
could anyone help me with it

Answer (score 0):

Here are things you can check:

- Is it running at all? You might have some other application running on port 80 (default if you haven't changed anything)
- Can you access it on the same machine it's running? Open your browser and go to `http://localhost/` - if it works, then it's a communication issue between the machines
- Can you see anything in the logs?
- Do you have any firewall running on the machine running XAMPP? If so, turn it off temporarily and see if it works - you should configure it properly and configure it afterwards

You should check the [FAQs](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/faq-xampp.html):

depending on the OS you are running it on.